# Extract a view from self.window in objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In my:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions:
```

I am setting the following `scrollView`:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
[self.window addSubview:scrollView];
```

In a later method, how would I then destroy this view, that is, remove it from `self.window`.

Comment: I assume you've tried storing a reference to it and calling `removeFromSuperview` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I wouldn't add a `scrollView` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Instead, create the `UIScrollView` in a View Controller, either in its `viewDidLoad` method, or in a Storyboard.

Either way, removing the `scrollView` would look something like this. First create a property to store the reference to the `UIScrollView`:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIScrollView *scrollView; // Use a weak reference to the scrollview, that way once its removed from the superview (which keeps a strong reference to its subviews), the scrollview will be deallocated.
```

Then initialize that property and add it as a subview:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect]; 
[self.window addSubview:scrollView];
```

Later, you can remove it:

```
[self.scrollView removeFromSuperview];
```